# Net GND's unconnected alert remains off in Altium

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, routing, cad

I have my Altium Designer project where I have a net called GND. That's the ground. While routing, I can see these little white lines that alert me about which pad I need to connect to each other, and it works perfect. These lines tell me the start and the end of my routes. The problem is that they are not telling me about connecting GND and I don't know why. I don't have any rule avoiding it, I know the name of the nets is exactly the same (actually, if I connect two GND pads with a route, it's ok), whatsmore, if I draw a plane with GND all the pads will connect to it. But I can't see the line telling me the need of a connection between two GND pads or between "islands" in my plane. And this is a huge problem, because I will not tell me if one pad remains unconnected! (If I run DRC, its all ok, even with islands or unconnected pads).
[image]

Comment: Moved to comment: Try View>Connections>Show all. I think GND and power nets are set not to display on the ratsnest by default (ratsnest is the name of the little white lines feature)

Comment: As for the DRC passing, try the steps in this FAQ: https://www.altium.com/documentation/knowledge-base/altium-designer/drc-doesnt-catch-unconnected-nets

Comment: @Entropy But if it is a matter of view settings, the DRC should not pass, and it does.

Comment: This link will take you to an excellent (and official) Altium resource: forum.live.altium.com

Comment: @DevelopingElectronics Follow the link I gave in my comment, it will take you to a fix for the issue you're describing